# Using Feign @HeaderMap with Springboot 1.5.4.RELEASE does not send headers

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I am trying to use feign.HeaderMap annotation to pass a map of HTTP headers in the rest request but these are appearing in the body.

Code below:

@FeignClient(name = "accounts", url = "localhost:8080")
public interface AccountClient {

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/rest/accounts/get", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
Account findOne(@RequestParam("id") String id, @HeaderMap Map headers);
```

}

Answer (score 8):

You are mixing annotations.  When using `spring-cloud-netflix` you will need to use the Spring annotation `@RequestHeader` instead.

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, 
        value = "/rest/accounts/get", 
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
Account findOne(@RequestParam("id") String id, @RequestHeader Map headers);
```

In `Feign` by default, all parameters not annotated will be serialized in the Body.